# Complex numbers - prove |BD| + |CD| = |AD|

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles

Let $ABC$ be equilateral triangle and $D$ be a point on the arc BC of the circle circumscribing ABC. Then prove using complex algebra that : $|BD| +|CD| = |AD|$.

For me, the confusion is both : (i)- in ability to think of problem, and (ii)- to formulate it.

(i) Ability  to think of problem : How is it possible that the two points nearest to $D$ have their arc lengths equal to that of $|AD|$, where A is the distant point. I cannot imagine by taking the shortest length of sum of $|BD| + |CD|$, or taking by a particular direction (cck, ck).

(ii) Unable to find a way to formulate, except possibly by taking the angle possible, and then would involve a range of $60^0$ for any point $D$ on the arc $BC$. Even then difficult to think of about the formulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A(a)$, $B(b)$, $C(c)$ and $D(z)$.

Thus, by Ptolemy $$AB\cdot DC+BD\cdot AC=AD\cdot BC$$ or
$$|a-b|\cdot |z-c|+|b-z|\cdot|a-c|=|a-z|\cdot |b-c|$$
and since $$|a-b|=|a-c|=|b-c|,$$ we obtain
$$|z-c|+|b-z|=|a-z|$$ or
$$CD+BD=AD.$$

Another way.

Let $A(1,0)$, $B(\cos120^{\circ}+i\sin120^{\circ})$, $C(\cos240^{\circ}+i\sin240^{\circ})$ and $D(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi)$,

where $120^{\circ}\leq\phi\leq240^{\circ}$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$\sqrt{(1-\cos\phi)^2+\sin^2\phi}=$$
$$=\sqrt{(\cos\phi-\cos120^{\circ})^2+(\sin\phi-\sin120^{\circ})^2}+\sqrt{(\cos\phi-\cos240^{\circ})^2+(\sin\phi-\sin240^{\circ})^2}$$ or
$$\sqrt{2-2\cos\phi}=\sqrt{2-2\cos(120^{\circ}-\phi)}+\sqrt{2-2\cos(240^{\circ}-\phi)}$$ or
$$\left|\sin\frac{\phi}{2}\right|=\left|\sin\left(60^{\circ}-\frac{\phi}{2}\right)\right|+\left|\sin\left(120^{\circ}-\frac{\phi}{2}\right)\right|$$ or

$$\sin\frac{\phi}{2}=\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{2}-60^{\circ}\right)+\sin\left(120^{\circ}-\frac{\phi}{2}\right),$$
which is an easy identity.

Comment: If I am not wrong, the solution would have been in analysis domain without complex numbers into picture. Then, very tough.

Comment: I used that $120^{\circ}\leq\phi\leq240^{\circ}$. Otherwise, we can not delete the absolute value.

Comment: Please elaborate: "Otherwise, we cannot delete the absolute value".

Comment: $\sin\frac{\phi}{2}$ can not be negative because $120^{\circ}\leq\phi\leq240^{\circ}$. Thus, $\sqrt{\sin^2\frac{\phi}{2}}=\left|\sin\frac{\phi}{2}\right|=\sin\frac{\phi}{2}.$ The rest is the same.

Comment: So, the solution cannot be easily adapted for other triangles, as need a real value for sine.

Comment: Yes, for another equilateral triangles. We can-not say here about the real value of $\sin$. We use that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ and we want to delete the $|.|$. We use that $\sqrt{2-2\cos\phi}=\sqrt{4\sin^2\frac{\phi}{2}}=2\left|\sin\frac{\phi}{2}\right|.$

Comment: I hope you meant : "only for equilateral triangles", although it is not clear why? Also, a positive value for square root operation, would yield a real value. I am sorry for asking it again, but I am not clear about:"We can-not say here about the real value of $\sin$."  Although irrelevant, I think sine in series expansion, the variable $x$ or $z$ can take any value : real or imaginary, i.e. as the complex value may be. So, stating an imaginary or real value of sine (as per expansion & the parameter's type) is possible.

Comment: An argument of the complex number is a real number by definition. Also, our $\sin$ and $\cos$ are reals. Points $A$, $B$ and $C$, which I defined they are vertexes of the equilateral triangle. See please better my second solution.